# Mysql Conditional Select-Join

Tags: mysql

I want to design a notification system for a website. In this system I hold the action and activity. Action specifies the table that I want to join with and the activity is the id of desired element. So for instance if I specify action as 1 I will go to table1 and get the record 'activity'. Rather than left joining all of the tables and eliminating null columns; I want more efficient way with conditional statement.

Comment: Then design it, and if you hit a problem then ask something specific.  If you've already designed something then more information such as table structure and sample queries/data would be helpful to determine what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding what you need, you want to use a value from one table to determine which table(s) to join.

As far as I know there wouldn't be a way to do it with only one query. Your best bet would probably be to construct the query in your website's code (PHP or whatever it is) and going from there.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's meant to scale and isn't a static list of a few tables, having a separate table based on an input variable seems to indicate database design that isn't generic enough.  Generally, this would be accomplished by having one table encompass all the sub-tables you would possibly be searching, with a new field to indicate which dataset you are looking for.

If the tables really aren't similar enough to be condensed into an encompassing table, then you probably have a lot more changing in your query than just the table name, in which case you want to be writing your query correctly for the task (with the right tables) from the beginning.  That means use different queries for different DB operations, most likely one per table, and write the query in the accessing programming language.